# Import Verisign SSL Certificate in Tomcat7

Tags: java, tomcat7, ssl-certificate, keystore

I am trying to install SSL certificate in Tomcat7. This is what i have done so far.

```
installed ssl certificate received on email

sudo ./keytool -import -trustcacerts -alias download.addressdoctor  -keystore /usr/local/tomcat7/bin/keystore.jks -file /usr/local/tomcat7/conf/certx509.cer

Installed Intermediate certificate

sudo ./keytool -import -trustcacerts -alias intermediate  -keystore /usr/local/tomcat7/bin/keystore.jks -file /usr/local/tomcat7/conf/combined.cer
```

These is my entries in keystore

```
Keystore type: JKS
Keystore provider: SUN

Your keystore contains 2 entries

Alias name: adnewkey
Creation date: Sep 10, 2014
Entry type: trustedCertEntry

Owner: CN=website.com, OU=IT, O=company, L=City, ST=state, C=country

*******************************************
*******************************************

Alias name: mykey
Creation date: Sep 10, 2014
Entry type: PrivateKeyEntry
Certificate chain length: 1
Certificate[1]:
Owner: CN=website.com, OU=IT, O=company
```

Now if i try to check the certificate through https://ssltools.websecurity.symantec.com/checker/views/certCheck.jsp

It says it is self signed certificate, whereas i installed the certificate received from verisign. If i remove the entry "alias mykey" then it will show error no root certificate found.

Can you please help me in pointing out what i am doing wrong, also for running SSL certificate what values should be present in the keystore.

Thanks,

Comment: You need to import the certificate received from Verisign with `-alias root`

Comment: Hi @Rp, No it is not working, i imported it again using the following command  sudo ./keytool -import -trustcacerts -alias download.addressdoctor  -keystore /usr/local/tomcat7/bin/keystore.jks -file /usr/local/tomcat7/conf/certx509.cer but still i am getting "This is not a Symantec certificate.
Please contact the Certificate Authority for further verification.
Recommendations
Root installed on the server.
For best practices, remove the self-signed root from the server."